# How much rep has Stack Overflow "gained" with unpaid bounty questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty

I'm a fan of the bounty questions. They normally are a bit more difficult to answer or require some more effort to get a working prototype. And of course, the added reputation and attention is nice too.

But I have the feeling that a lot of the bounty reputation isn't rewarded. Maybe because the user received their answer and forgot to award the bounty in time, or your answer is not accepted and automatically you only receive half the points.

Now reading meta I noticed some people can perform queries on the database and I was wondering, just out of curiosity:

how much would Stack Overflow have gained if we treated it like a bank or a bookmaker?

In such that the rep to start a bounty is the bet you make that you'll get your answer and if it's rewarded; that's the payout.

- How much was bet the last year?
- How much has been paid?
- What's the "profit" for Stack Overflow?
- What's the average bet and payout per question?

**Update**

See [Bounty stats. What can a Bounty do for you?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/196596/bounty-stats-what-can-a-bounty-do-for-you?opt.textResults=true) <sup>*You need to run the query to get the conclusions*</sup>

Comment: Why not make the database queries yourself? You can do so at http://data.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Ah, thought it was a privilege. Then indeed I can do it myself. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Sample bounty-related query: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67068

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I have created the queries myself and tried to create some easy to read output, hence the long/strange queries.

See [Bounty stats. What can a Bounty do for you?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/196596/bounty-stats-what-can-a-bounty-do-for-you?opt.textResults=true)

**Conclusions**

- We spent **704,250** reputation to start bounties last year.
- We received **419,125** reputation back from Stack Overflow.
- Stack Overflow's profit: **285,125**
- We lost **40.49%** of our reputation in the process.
- Starting a bounty will increase viewcount with **317.57%**
- Starting a bounty will increase question score with **1,075.86%**
- Starting a bounty will increase question reputation with **-4,844.90%**
- Starting a bounty will increase answer reputation with **309.32%**

I've updated the query to include the accepted answers. Which brings the following two conclusions:

- It's less likely that your answers will be the accepted answer on a bounty question (**8%** less chance)
- **58%** of bounty questions have an accepted answer. Thats **16%** higher then regular questions.

Comment: I had only a superficial look at your bounty stats, but shouldn't the reputation for answers include +15 for the accepted answer?

Comment: You are right. I dont have time to include this minor change now, but i'll edit asap.

Comment: (285,125 / 704,250) = %40; That's a bigger margin than Apple. It's beginning to look alot like Tennis, Rackets everywhere !!

Comment: The House Always Wins!

Comment: I don't think that 40.49% number is correct; as worded it seems to imply that over 40% of ALL reputation has been lost.  What actual percentage of total rep has been spent on bounties?

Comment: Maybe the wording is wrong. But the number is correct. Only 40% of the rep we put in a bounty is returned. Not counting regular rep gain with votes and accepted awnser