# Half bounty because asker didn't care

Tags: discussion, bounty

I gave answering questions on Stack Overflow a try and figured I'd start with a particularly time-consuming one: [Save vertices to texture and pass to shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544383/save-vertices-to-texture-and-pass-to-shader/23695617#23695617)

The OP hadn't received any answer for a while and probably therefore set a bonus of 50 points. I answered the question with a lot of effort (as you can see) and in the end I did not only provide theoretical insight and cleared misunderstandings, but I also helped him to get on with the code.

Now of course after the issue was resolved he didn't care about the topic anymore and also didn't accept my answer. I was lucky enough to get 2 upvotes and therefore got half the points - but still. I find this highly demotivating. Is there something I could've done or is this "just the way it works" on SO?

Comment: That's just the way it works, really. If the OP didn't mark your answer as accepted, and did not manually award the bonus, you only get half the amount. You cannot force an OP to interact, and when they don't then that's really 'it'.

Comment: And for some perspective, this is still **better** than not gaining **any** reputation at all.

Comment: Noticed the same with my own answers. After some queries I found that more than 40% of offered bounty is just lost. see [How much rep has stackoverflow “gained” with unpaid bounty questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255781/434949)

Comment: Note you got 60 from the upvotes, and 25 from the bounty: 50 point bounties are really not worth that much karma.  You would have gotten 40 more had the asker properly marked you as the recipient.  Second, if you want to know if the extra effort is likely to be worthwhile, look at the askers history of marking an answer as accepted: not very good for that asker, I'll note.

Comment: Just to stick up for the OP, it could be that RL caught them and they weren't able to come back to SO towards the end of the bounty.  No need to ascribe malice.

Comment: You just got another upvote.

Comment: further up votes won't result in reputation for Doidel, he hit the reputation cap already.

Comment: Just as a point to add, I don't think the UI is immediately clear on the fact that you have to manually press the +50 button to award the bounty.

Comment: It's fairly easy for the OP to be waiting in case there are any other answers and unintentionally let the bounty period expire.  Yes, there are warnings, but they're like "The bounty will expire in 17 hours" and then no more warnings (don't recall the exact sequence) and suddenly the bounty has expired.

Comment: Wow, 255 rep and a silver badge now from that one answer.  There's a lesson to be learned here.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Lesson: don't be timid about complaining on meta

Comment: Well, I posted [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989819/theory-on-error-handling/23456719#23456719) because I had some interest in the subject and I owe the OP for [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/). He appreciated the answer (and upvoted it), but that's all. No bounty (it was awarded to [a better answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23449090/147192)) and the system decided the answers would be community wiki anyway... oh well ;)

Comment: @Doidel ... people are assholes.  I'm so sorry this happened to you.  Your best bet is to just be bitter and never help newbs again  :O  Sweet code...

Comment: In the good-olde-days, this user would have his 57% acceptance rate prominently displayed.  You'd at least have some expectation of your work being treated like navel lint.  Yet another thing we lost...

Comment: @MatthieuM. "system decided the answers would be community wiki" - really? I was told just the day that "we" could decide if our posts should be CW or not.

Comment: If there was any flaw at all then it was questioners focusing on a perfect 100% score *way* too much.  It was a pretty darn handy help vampire detector.  I assume the constant whining about it in meta is what got it killed.  The ~1% of SO users that actually post answers can't have nice things...

Comment: You had a learning experience (or brushed up on something you already knew) and helped someone out, isn't that supposed to be the reward? I think there's a broader life lesson here, don't do something simply because you expect something in return.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Boy, that sucks :(. I think it is the way it just works, it's a risk when answering a question with a bounty.

You chose to answer a question in quadrant D:

[image: question quadrants]

This is an awesome quadrant! Make sure you invest effort in answering these questions if you:

- Enjoy helping *fewer* people, but help them with a *hard* problem; and/or
- Want to learn something about that specific problem yourself;

**Use bounties as a trigger to spike your interest, not to motivate yourself in answering.** The stuff that happened to you sucks, but it is indeed the way it works. If you choose the right reasons for answering "B" questions though, you'll still probably get enough satisfaction.

Getting an incidental upvote for an answer to a hard, specific question can be as rewarding as getting 10 upvotes to a quick answer to an easy, broad question.

PS. Although being pushy about upvotes and accepting answers is generally considered impolite, I think it's very reasonable to leave a friendly comment explaining to the OP that accepting your answer would've been nice as it would've gotten you the full bounty. If you do this *after* the fact (e.g.: now) you wouldn't even come across as pushy IMO, as it won't benefit you anymore (only other "victims" of this unknowing or lazy OP).

Comment: _"Use bounties as a trigger to spike your interest, not to motivate yourself in answering"_ That. That's clear thinking. And convincing advice.

Comment: +1 Love the quadrant diagram.  Given my area of expertise and the languages I know, I'm in quadrant D all the time.  When answering those kinds of questions, I have learned more about my field and my primary programming language in the 3 or so months since I have been a member of SO more than I have in my entire post-grad education.

Comment: Is it irony that he hasnt marked this as an answer? ;)

Comment: Gotta love the irony!

Comment: It was away on the weekend, I did it now ^^ Thanks for all the positive feedback!

Comment: There is one important thing which should be added: Because a bounty is advertizing (as you alluded), there will be considerably more visitors, including voters, while it is active.